# How to generate sequential numbers in an Identity column

Tags: sql-server-2012, identity-column

I have a database table Person with primary key ID, I set the identifier specification to "Yes" and the identity increment to 1 to make it auto-increment.

But all I am having are random numbers like 1, 33, 34, 1034, 1035, 2036, 3036, 4037

I want to make it Sequential like 1 2 3 etc...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Start by posting the relevant code at least. If you want to know how to ask good questions see the document [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to show us what you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Questions about Stack Overflow itself should be posted on https://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: [Stop making assumptions about `IDENTITY`](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-making-assumptions-about-identity), stop worrying about gaps - they are really **NOT** a problem!

Answer (score 0):

An identity column guarantees sequential values but allows gaps.  Gaps may occur due to row deletion, transaction rollbacks, server restart, or concurrency.  If you don't want gaps, don't use IDENTITY.  Consider using ROW_NUMBER() in your queries instead of you don't want gaps.